# How to Add Custom Increment and decrements Counter in jQuery Ui Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I am trying to increase the `width` of an element (`.inner`) using jQuery Ui slider. This is somehow working fine **but** I need to keep the `center` of the `inner` always in the center of `.wrapper`. so I think I need to add negative values for `top` and `left` but I do not know how to achieve them. Do I have to create two custom counter there or is there any better way to achieve this?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 300,
    max: 1000,
    value: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $(".inner").css({
        "width": ui.value,
        "height": ui.value
      });
     }
  });

});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper ">
  <div class="inner"> Center </div>
</div>
<br />
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Comment: Please check the answer. I decided I want to reach 2000 in a few weeks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the width of the div and the range of the slider were the same, I used the slider value to change the left and top positions of the inner div.
This was of course possible because it was in position `absolute`.

Only half the value of the slider is applied, because to be centered you should split the change on left/right and top/bottom. Obviously adding the `right` or `bottom` css property would be pointless, since one is enough to properly position your element.

```js
$(function() {
  var $inner = $(".inner");
  var lastValue = 300;
  $("#slider").slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 300,
    max: 1000,
    value: 300,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      var curLeft = $inner.position().left;
      var curTop = $inner.position().top;
      var toAdd = (lastValue - ui.value) /2;

      $inner.css({
        "width": ui.value,
        "height": ui.value,
        "top": curTop + toAdd,
        "left": curLeft + toAdd,
      });
      
      lastValue = ui.value;
     }
  });

});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper ">
  <div class="inner"> Center </div>
</div>
<br />
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sampgun the increasing works perfectly. I am trying to understand how to decrease it properly too

Comment: I figured it out! I didn't have to change the sign, because I was already calculating the difference with the last value!! Now it works!

Comment: Nope. Maybe I always have to change the sign...wait a sec